# Best size for modal

Tags: modal

I am designing a modal for enterprise application. What is the optimal size for modal width and height. I need to design one for small medium and large..

Is there a resource or user research done around optimal sizes?

Comment: I think it really depends on the content that you are using the modal to display. Whether you need three sizes, or you create the size relative to the current display dimensions, the optimal design will come down to the amount of content you have to show.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the **design system** or **library** that the system uses.

If design custom styles, sizes can be any (within reason)

if software is built on a library, they usually have built-in module modules with specific parameters.

---

If  [Click here](https://bashooka.com/inspiration/modal-window-ui-designs/) - You will see  a great variety of modals  they all differ in shape.

It's everything based on your software **criteria** & **standards**.

---

For example in Wordpress:

**Size |    Class | Modal max-width**

- Small    | .modal-sm | 300px -default
- Large    | .modal-lg | 800px
- Extra large  | .modal-xl |   1140px